# How to prevent the on click action inside in div class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to close the modal by clicking the cross icon which is in the modal and the modal is rendered inside a td and the whole tr is made clickable. I am using tailwind for my CSS. The problem is the modal does not get closed on click the cross icon.

```
 <tr onclick= "show_modal(this)">
          <td><%=device&.name%></td> 
          <td ><%= render partial: 'edit', locals: {device: device}%></td>
          </tr>
```

Partial file(_edit.html.erb)

```
<div class="modal-holder js_modal_container modal__hidden">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h5>device</h5>
      <i class="fas fa-times js_device_modal_close_btn" onclick="close_modal(this)"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- modal body -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js i have tried.

```
 window.show_modal =function(e){
  let js_modal_container = $(e).find(".js_modal_container")
  if ($(this).is("td:last-child")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(js_modal_container).addClass("modal__hidden");
    $(document.body).removeClass("overlay__handler");
  };
  $(js_modal_container).removeClass("modal__hidden");
  $(document.body).addClass("overlay__handler");
}

window.close_modal = function(e){
  let js_modal_container= $(e).closest(".js_modal_container")
  a =$(e).closest(".modal_popup")
  if ($(a).is("td:last-child")){
    // e.preventDefault();
    // e.stopPropagation();
    $(js_modal_container).addClass("modal__hidden");
    $(document.body).removeClass("overlay__handler");
  }
  // $(js_modal_container).addClass("modal__hidden");
  // $(document.body).removeClass("overlay__handler");
}
```

Comment: The code you have here should work if the elment can be clicked on, but make sure that element is not "under" the modal. If it is, the click event will only be upon the modal. Again, it should still work. Any console errors or alerts? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: On clicking the close icon the modal popup again. @twisty

Comment: I've removed the `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails` tags. You may have a file called `_edit.html.erb`, but that doesn't make this a question about either of those technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function openModal(e) {
    console.log("Open Modal Fired.");
    var $this = $(e.target);
    console.log($this.text().trim());
    var js_modal_container = $(".js_modal_container");
    $(".modal-header h5").html($this.prev("td").text().trim());
    js_modal_container.removeClass("modal__hidden");
    $(document.body).addClass("overlay__handler");
  }

  function closeModal(e) {
    console.log("Close Modal Fired.");
    var $this = $(e.target);
    var js_modal_container = $this.closest(".js_modal_container");
    js_modal_container.addClass("modal__hidden");
    $(document.body).removeClass("overlay__handler");
  }

  $("table tr").on("click", "td:last-child", openModal);
  $("i.js_device_modal_close_btn").click(closeModal);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 340px;
}

td:last-child {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}

.modal__hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Device Name 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Edit
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Device Name 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Edit
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Device Name 3
    </td>
    <td>
      Edit
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="modal-holder js_modal_container modal__hidden">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5>device</h5>
    <i class="fas fa-times js_device_modal_close_btn"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- modal body -->
  </div>
</div>
```

For ease of use, I have created two functions to use and bound them to `click` events on various elements in the page. For the Edit item, I used `.on()` in case they are not available when the page initially loads or if new items are appended.

`$(e)` is not an element, but an event. We need to look at the Event Target: `e.target`. This will return an element that can be used as a jQuery Object: `$(e.target)`. I suspect this was the primary issue in your code. The rest is just for clarification of the example.